# Problem displaying data in Datatable using a Stored Procedure

Tags: php, ajax, stored-procedures, datatables

I have the following problem when I want to visualize data in the famous Datatable library using a Store Procedure made in SQLServer, I use the Store Procedure to display my information in the table, the problem is that my data is not being reflected in the table, so this I use PHP and AJAX.

To see the information in my Datatable I use its API to attach secondary rows better known as [Child Rows](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html), the following is the AJAX code with which I build my table and its parameters:

```
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Currency</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.Currency+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        
    '</table>';
}
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
       // "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            url :"../utileria.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                param: 1,               
            },
        },
        columns: [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data" : "Order_Buy" },        
            { "data" : "Currency" },           
           
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );

    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );
 
        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
} );
```

It is important to note that my parent row will contain the **Order_Buy** field and my child row the **Currency** field

The following is my PHP code where I call my Stored Procedure and the class `conectar.php`

**utileria.php**

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');   
    $param = $_POST['param'];   
    switch($param) {
        case '1':               
                $query = array();
                include 'conectar.php';
                $sql = "{call SPTest(?)}";          
                $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
                if ( $stmt === false) {
                    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
                }   
                while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                    $record = array(
                        "F.ORDER"       => utf8_encode ($row['Order_Buy']), //Orden de compra
                        "F.CURRENCY"          => utf8_encode ($row['Currency']), //Moneda
                       
                    );
                    array_push($query, $record);
                }
                echo json_encode($query);
                sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);       
                sqlsrv_close($conn);

            break;
    
    }
    
?>
```

I do not know why my table does not show me data, it could be that I have something wrong in any of my codes.

If it helps to give a better clarity of the question I attach the HTML code with which I generate my Datatables table.

```
!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libraries/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libraries/css/estilos.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="libraries/js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/Example.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>    
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.24/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="libraries/img/icon.png" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="cuerpo">
        <div class="dividir menu">
            <div class="centrar-vertical">
                <img src="libraries/img/logo.jpg" width="200" height="40" alt="Test" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="alinear-derecha centrar-vertical">              
                <button id="logout-btn" class="btn btn-default">Cerrar Sesión</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tablaDatatable">  
        <table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Order_Buy</th>                  
                    <th>Currency</th>                                                
                </tr>              
            </thead>
        </table>        
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: What is the structure of your raw JSON, coming from `utileria.php`? Take a look at the [expected JSON structure](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) when using `serverSide: true`. See the "returned data" and "Example data" sections.

Comment: Why do you use `utf8_encode`?

Comment: @Dharman I use it to encode a string of characters that we have in ISO-8859-1 into another string with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Well, that is actually correct usage, but then a follow up question: why do you even have strings in Latin1 charset?

Comment: @andrewjames I do not use any JSON structure, in my file `utileria.php` is the code that I attached in my question

Comment: Understood - but that PHP code needs to return a valid JSON response to DataTables. What is the structure of that response? And does that structure match what DataTables expects it to be?

Comment: @Dharman This is because some of the strings that will be shown will be in Spanish.

Comment: No, I am confused. Why are you not storing the data in UTF8 in the first place?

Comment: @Dharman What is the difference between utf8_enconde and utf8?

Comment: @andrewjames 
If you look at my PHP code, it performs the JSON response `echo json_encode ($ query);` and if it matches what Datatables expects, the same if you want to validate in the code that I have in my question

Comment: `utf8_encode` is a special PHP function with a very limited functionality for converting from one character encoding to another. UTF-8 is a type of character encoding. It is the most popular one. All your database tables and columns have to be encoded with a selected character encoding; this is how the database stores string data. When connecting to the database you have to specify the connection charset so that the data is also encoded properly. Do not use `utf8_encode` as it looks like some sort of hack to fix a more serious issue. Ensure that you have set the right charset everywhere

Comment: @Dharman What do you recommend I use for the case of special characters?

Comment: There are no special characters. Store everything as UTF-8 data. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: @Dharman That may be the error for which it is not showing me data in my table?

Answer (score 0):

I have written a js datagrid as I was not happy with any of the available sources, just try it if you are after a data tables Hope it benefit you.

[JS Datargid on github](https://github.com/YaserFarghaly/Javascript-Data-Grid)

cheers